# Every closed separable subspace is complemented

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Suppose that every closed separable subspace $Y$ of $X$ is complemented in $X$ (i.e., there is a bounded linear projection of $X$ onto $Y$). Is $X$ necessarilly isomorphic to a Hilbert space?

Note: If $X$ is separable, or if every closed subspace $Y$ of $X$ (not necessarilly separable) is complemented in $X$, then the answer is positive, as proved by Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri (1977) (and pointed out by Harald Hanche-Olsen in the comment below).

Comment: I don't know, but it might be worthwhile to note (for the benefit of bystanders) that the answer is yes, if $X$ is separable, or if you drop the separability requirement on $Y$. This is due to a result by Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri [mentioned here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplementarySubspaceProblem.html). And on a more trivial note, that you mean to ask if $X$ is *isomorphic* to a Hilbert space, since it is clearly not necessarily isometric to one.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the question.

Comment: I would say "yes". As pointed out by Harald, your assumption implies (by Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri) that any separable subspace $Z$ of $X$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space. So any such $Z$ has type 2 and cotype 2. It follows that $X$ itself has type 2 and cotype 2, since these properties should be easily seen to be "separably determined" (if you write down what it means that $X$ does not have, say, type $2$, then you realize that it is possible to produce a separable subspace $Z$ which does not have type $2$). Now, apply Kwapien's theorem (!) to conclude that $X$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am not familiar with the definition of type and cotype of a Banach space so I will have to spend some time to think about what you wrote.

Comment: Maybe there is a simpler proof. Anyway, I can write a more detailed answer if it can help.

Comment: @Etienne, amazing!

Comment: $Z$ is separable, so any subspace $Y$ of $Z$ is separable as well, hence complemented in $X$. If you restrict the corresponding projection to $Z$, this gives you a continuous projection from $Z$ onto $Y$. Is it correct?

Comment: @Norbert : thanks! I still wonder if there is a simpler proof using "only" Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri.

Comment: @Etienne Ah, yes. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @Etienne Another similar way would be to use the fact that if $X$ is not isomorphic to a Hilbert space, then the sequence of Euclidean distances $d_n(X)=sup\{d(l_2^n, E), \mbox{dim}E=n\}$ is unbounded. This fact again follows immediately from type/cotype arguments, but I don't remember whether there is a more immediate proof.

Comment: @Theo Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Etienne Give me a few days (I am quite busy atm) and then I will let you know whether I need a more detailed answer. Thank you.